# Python - Sending Variable to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a list of IP addresses that I need to run a `curl` command on Remotely. 
I am using a `for` loop to iterate through the ips.

The command that I need to run remotely is

```
curl --silent http://<IP>:9200/_cat/master | awk '{print $2}'
```

The above output will return an IP address of a master node in my cluster.

My code states

```
status = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % ip, "curl http://ip:9200/_cat/master | awk '{print $2}'"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I am having trouble passing the `ip` variable as part of my command.

I have also tried doing this.

```
status = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % ip, "curl http://",ip,":9200/_cat/master | awk '{print $2}'"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But it does not seem to work.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: Do you need to SSH to the machine to execute the command?

Comment: @Pigueiras  Due to firewall limitations, the curl commands can only be run on the node I am logged on to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter will likely work better as one string.  Try:

```
status = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ssh", "%s" % ip, 
     "curl http://%s:9200/_cat/master | awk '{print $2}'" % ip
    ], ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I recall trying things your way, passing in the list, but had a lot of issues.

Instead, I've settled on passing in a single execution string just about everywhere in my code.

```
popen = subprocess.Popen(
"ping -n 1 %s" % "192.168.1.10",
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
```

The one case where I used the list is an extremely simple exe call

```
popen = Popen( [sys.executable, script_name], stdout=output_file, stderr=output_file )
```